# Setting up DB in client computer for WPF

Tags: sql-server, wpf, visual-studio, clickonce

I have a wpf application developed with VS2015 community edition. I'm done with the development. I want to test it in the client computer. The program uses SQL database. I installed Microsoft SQL in the computer where it was developed. How to setup a db in the client computer? Is there a easier solution other than azure or installing Microsoft SQL in the client's computer. I wish to publish it as a ClickOnce application. Please give a simple solution. Thank you.

Comment: So , you want to install that app in another machine without install SQL Server?

Comment: @Sami Yes. That's what i expect

Comment: ok , [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343.aspx) please. That's the only way.